# How to pattern match on a Future Result when it is the Action is of AnyContent type

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a action that looks like:

```
def login(...): Action[AnContent] = 
   customActionBuilder.async { request =>

}
```

Now this customActionBuilder will return either:

1. execute the passed in block
2. Future.successful(...) with a InternalServerError

So from within my action I want to pattern match against the type of result to perform some custom logic in that action e.g. if it is a InternalServerError

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does it return `Future.succesful` on error?

Comment: Because the future is still returning succesfully, the response just has a error type I guess... I can't change that part it is not my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities depending on what you want to do as "custom logic".

A `Filter` might be appropriate if you want to apply it in a global way for all `Action`s. You will be able to intercept the response and read it's headers (status code) to do custom logic.

You could also compose another `ActionBuilder`.